# Error 508 shows up in my WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I recently encountered error 508 on my WordPress blog. This error started when I installed Human theme. After it, I am even unable to log in my WordPress dashboard. I even reverted back the changes but of no use. Please tell me how can I solve it. I also contacted my host and they told me to optimise my website. Please tell me how to solve it . my blog is trickedpc.com

Answer (score 0):

The 508 error means that there is a loop detected. So I think there is something wrong in the theme.

If you have access to the database you could switch back to the default (or another) theme by changing the values of the template and stylesheet options in the wp_options table. You can find these values with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'template' OR `option_name` LIKE 'stylesheet';
```

If you change the option_value of both options back to twentyfourteen or another theme you can probably access your site again.

Comment: I got this error - but it was on different wp sites all with different themes which makes me doubt the potential solution given. MM